# Align Div/Checkbox in Div using CSS

Tags: html, css

There is the following code:

```
<div class="form-group ng-scope">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="without_duration">Without duration</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <input class="ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" type="checkbox" ng-model="news.without_duration" name="without_duration">
  </div>
</div>
```

Problem is the following one: I have some text in label, but checkbox is not aligned with the label by vertically. How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you also post the style applied to this code please?

Comment: Check it vertically aligned. http://jsfiddle.net/Lb6qc4ms/

Comment: I mean on the same row

Comment: like: http://jsfiddle.net/Lb6qc4ms/1/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Since those are floated, add `margin-top` to the div containing the checkbox so that it aligns vertically with the label.

Comment: Where did you see they are floated?

Comment: col-sm classes in bootstrap have float:left;

Answer (score 0):

This part of css can save you quickly:

```
label, input{
    float: left;
}
```

but give some class to label and input, because you don't want to affect all inputs and labels on your site.
[Codepen Sample](http://codepen.io/zlajaa1/pen/GJooZe)

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
}
.col-sm-9 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Will give your desired output.

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lb6qc4ms/1/)

Comment: Can you add jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Well you just need to use bootstrap class `pull-left` on `label` and `div` as shown **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/7515/)**

```
<div class="form-group ng-scope">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label pull-left" for="without_duration">Without duration</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <input class="ng-untouched ng-valid pull-left ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" type="checkbox" ng-model="news.without_duration" name="without_duration">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Problem**: As `div` is `display: block;` so the checkbox goto next line ...

**Solution**: **[JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/7515/)**, Apply `float: left;` to the `label` and `div` !!

Answer (score 0):

Please check below i eneter details

```html
<div class="form-group ng-scope">
   <div class="col-sm-9"> <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="without_duration">Without duration</label>

    <input class="ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" type="checkbox" ng-model="news.without_duration" name="without_duration">
  </div>
</div>
</pre>
or

<div class="form-group ng-scope">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="without_duration">Without duration</label>

    <input class="ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" type="checkbox" ng-model="news.without_duration" name="without_duration">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your answer?

Comment: yeah here code html he/she used a div  so default after complete div the next tag  may be in shift to new line so  if either you  can edit html or apply css on html  thanks a lot